# How to get the only PDF url from web page?

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, web-scraping, dom

I am trying to get some DOM elements using Selenium and I am doing all of this using Java but I am getting this Error when trying it out:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

I am still a newbie in all this but the code I am using to retrieve the DOM element is:

```
 driver.get("https://www.qp.alberta.ca/570.cfm?frm_isbn=9780779808571&search_by=link");
String pagePdfUrl = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@alt='View PDF']//..//parent::a")).getAttribute("href");
```

I believe the error is that it cannot find the XPath given although this xpath exists. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: It seems you are trying to read the pdf DOM elements. Is that correct? If yes, are you looking for any value from pdf?

Comment: That is correct. I am trying to read the pdf URL from the pdf dom elements

Comment: Please share the pdf sample if possible else the url text how it looks.

Comment: Why cannot you read pdf content for url?

Comment: https://www.qp.alberta.ca/documents/Acts/A01.pdf this is the pdf sample. I am trying to read the pdf content for URL using the code above but the error above is showing up that is the problem

Comment: You cannot find element for PDF documents. When you try to inspect it will be open the DOM in dev tools that means it's not attached to the source. I have gone through the PDF there is no URL inside PDF? What's the URL you are looking for? Like this `Shop on-line at www.qp.alberta.ca`

Comment: I am looking for the URL of the pdf itself, not a URL inside the pdf but rather the PDF URL it as it is, the one I have shared with you

Comment: Then you have to mention that clearly. Is it possible to share that page URL?

Comment: My apologies, I will do better. Yes, qp.alberta.ca/documents/Acts/A01.pdf is the URL I want to retrieve.

Comment: I am asking in which web page this pdf url resides?

Comment: Oh, it's https://www.qp.alberta.ca/570.cfm and I get to the PDF by clicking the first act there and following through

Comment: Posted an answer. Please see and let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- There is a `href` attribute is having pdf URL but that `URL` opens the pdf within webpage.
- So I extracted the pdf `URL` from `href` attribute and fetched the pdf name from that then concatenated with `https://www.qp.alberta.ca/documents/Acts/` URL.

You can write the code like below to get the pdf URL.

#### **Code to get `PDF` URL**:

```
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    /*I hard coded below URL. You need parameterize based on your requirement.*/
    driver.get("https://www.qp.alberta.ca/570.cfm?frm_isbn=9780779808571&search_by=link");
    String pagePdfUrl = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@alt='View PDF']//..//parent::a")).getAttribute("href");
    System.out.println("Page PDF URL: " + pagePdfUrl);
    String pdfName = StringUtils.substringBetween(pagePdfUrl, "page=", ".cfm&");
    driver.get("https://www.qp.alberta.ca/documents/Acts/" + pdfName + ".pdf");
```

#### **Code to download `PDF`**:

**Required ChromOptions:**

```
   ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
   HashMap<String, Object> chromeOptionsMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
       chromeOptionsMap.put("plugins.plugins_disabled", new String[] { "Chrome PDF Viewer" });
       chromeOptionsMap.put("plugins.always_open_pdf_externally", true);
       chromeOptionsMap.put("download.default_directory", "C:\\Users\\Downloads\\test\\");
       options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromeOptionsMap);
       options.addArguments("--headless");
```

**Accessing PDF:**

```
    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    driver.get("https://www.qp.alberta.ca/570.cfm?frm_isbn=9780779808571&search_by=link");
    String pagePdfUrl = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@alt='View PDF']//..//parent::a")).getAttribute("href");
    System.out.println("Page PDF URL: " + pagePdfUrl);
    String pdfName = StringUtils.substringBetween(pagePdfUrl, "page=", ".cfm&");
    System.out.println("Only PDF URL: "+"https://www.qp.alberta.ca/documents/Acts/" + pdfName + ".pdf");
    driver.get("https://www.qp.alberta.ca/documents/Acts/" + pdfName + ".pdf");
```

**OutPut**:

```
Page PDF URL: https://www.qp.alberta.ca/1266.cfm?page=2017ch18_unpr.cfm&leg_type=Acts&isbncln=9780779808571
Only PDF URL: https://www.qp.alberta.ca/documents/Acts/2017ch18_unpr.pdf
```

**Import for `StringUtils`**:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
```

Comment: When testing out code for getting pdf URL, I get this exception: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Comment: At what line you are getting this error? Please refer this to solve https://stackoverflow.com/a/69431779/7731623

Comment: I am unsure what line, it is not showing me what line but it refers to the XPath element not being found

Comment: Please debug and see

Comment: this is the line it is referring to,         String pagePdfUrl = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@alt='View PDF']//..//parent::a")).getAttribute("href");

Comment: Please update the question with what code you are trying

Comment: And have you tried the solution from what I referred https://stackoverflow.com/a/69431779/7731623

Comment: I got it to work! Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad.. it helped you :)